# MySQL don't select a row

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I need to get the titles of 3 recent posts, but leave out a specific one, if it comes up as one of the 3 most recent ones.

I got this:

```
SELECT
  postID,
  title
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  categoryID = $categoryID
ORDER BY
  date DESC
LIMIT
  3
```

This works fine, but I need to tell if to leave out the row where "postID = $postID"
"$postID" is the post that shouldn't be displayed and is defined before.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the DISTINCT keyword?

Comment: It looks like they are just trying to exclude a row if the postID is something in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another condition to the `where` clause to filter that specific `postId`

```
SELECT
  postID,
  title
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  categoryID = $categoryID
AND
  postID <> $postID
ORDER BY
  date DESC
LIMIT
  3
```

Comment: aah yes! Got it now. Had this before but didn't work because of a mistake I made in the code before. Thanks! Helped me anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
  SELECT
      postID,
      title
    FROM
      posts
    WHERE
      categoryID = $categoryID
    AND
      postID != $postID
    ORDER BY
      date DESC
    LIMIT
      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding you correctly?  You just want to omit the postID equal to $postID?

```
SELECT
  postID,
  title
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  categoryID = $categoryID
AND
  postID <> $postID
ORDER BY
  date DESC
LIMIT
  3
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the expected results using the <> operator:

```
SELECT
  postID,
  title
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  categoryID = $categoryID
  AND postID <> $postID
ORDER BY
  date DESC
LIMIT
  3
```